# Ubuntu - Apache - Reverse Proxy - NodeJS 302 : moved permanently on post method

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy

I have an application running on my VPS at http://localhost:3000.
I'm trying to make a reverse Proxy with Apache2 to make it accessible at node.mydomain.net.

With that virtualhost config :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
ServerName node.mydomain.net
ServerAlias www.node.mydomain.net
</VirtualHost>
```

It's actually working with the welcome page, but when i'm trying to connect, the POST method to node.mydomain.net/authenticate, it's actually return in the web inspector : 
request method : POST Status Code : 302 Moved Temporarily.

Im' not sure about the real problem and I found no solution by the moment. Can it a rewriting problem ? or a POST method not allowed problem ?

If anyone can send me on a serious trail, i'll be very happy.

Many thanks.

Comment: Moved to where? What's the `Location` header say? Also, are you sure it's not your Node app that's doing a redirect?

Comment: Location : connexion (/connexion is the default, welcome page).

Comment: In local dev environment, the Node app works pretty well

Comment: My guess is that it's your Node app that's generating that redirect, most likely because the authentication was successful.

Comment: the welcome page is : node.mydomain.net/connexion. when the authentification form is submitted, forms datas are sent (POST) to node.mydomain.net/authenticate. And on the route /authenticate, datas are evaluated, if it's correct the user is redirected to node.mydomain.net/users/welcome. It's working pretty well in local environment, so i really think it's a POST method authorization problem or a bad configuration of my apache server.

Comment: Where would the user get redirected if the user data was _incorrect_? Back to `/connexion`?

Comment: Finally i found a solution, the configuration is good, it's the conversion of my mongo database that was bad, sorry for the inconvenience ! Thank you